# R group by date, and summarize the values

Tags: r, date, time

R is new for me and I am working with a (private) data set.

I have the following problem, I have a lot of time series:

```
2015-04-27  12:29:48
2015-04-27  12:31:48
2015-04-27  12:34:50
2015-04-27  12:50:43
2015-04-27  12:53:55
2015-04-28  00:00:00
2015-04-28  00:00:10
```

All the timeseries have a value:

```
Datetime                   value
2015-04-27  12:29:48       0.0 
2015-04-27  12:31:48       0.0
2015-04-27  12:34:50       1.1
2015-04-27  12:50:43      45.0 
2015-04-27  12:53:55       0.0
2015-04-28  00:00:00       1.0
2015-04-28  00:00:10       2.0
```

I want to skip all the hours and minutes, and sum it all together like this:

```
Datetime      value
2015-04-27    46.1
2015-04-28     3.0
```

The first thing i did was transform the column datetime:

```
energy$datetime <- as.POSIXlt(energy$datetime)
```

I tried the summarize function:

```
df %>% group_by(energy$datetime) %>% summarize (energy$newname(energy$value))
```

But that isn't working.

I also read competitive stuff on the internet (e.g.: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-sum-and-group-data-by-DATE-in-data-frame-td903708.html) but it doesn't make sense to me.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try `energy %>% group_by(datetime) %>% summarize(newvar =mean(value))` The first thing in that line is your dataframe, and you don't need to specify it in the following calls. See http://www.r-bloggers.com/magrittr-simplifying-r-code-with-pipes/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `as.Date()` then `aggregate()`.

```
energy$Date <- as.Date(energy$Datetime)
aggregate(energy$value, by=list(energy$Date), sum)
```

#### EDIT

Emma made a good point about column names. You can preserve column names in `aggregate` by using the following instead:

```
aggregate(energy["value"], by=energy["Date"], sum)
```

Comment: It is sometimes very helpful to name your column names. `aggr_energy <-aggregate(energy$value, by=list(energy$Date), sum) `                                            
                                                                              
  `colnames(aggr_energy) <- c('date', 'medium', 'pageviews')`

Comment: @Emma Or even more simply, `aggregate(energy["value"], by=energy["Date"], sum)`, should preserve the column names.

Answer (score 6):

Using the tidyverse, specifically lubridate and dplyr:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
df <- tibble(Datetime = sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2015-04-27"), as.POSIXct("2015-04-29"), by = "min"), 10),
            value = sample(1:100, 10)) %>%
  arrange(Datetime)

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    Datetime            value
#>    <dttm>              <int>
#>  1 2015-04-27 04:04:00    35
#>  2 2015-04-27 10:48:00    41
#>  3 2015-04-27 13:02:00    25
#>  4 2015-04-27 13:09:00     5
#>  5 2015-04-27 14:43:00    57
#>  6 2015-04-27 20:29:00    12
#>  7 2015-04-27 20:34:00    77
#>  8 2015-04-28 00:22:00    66
#>  9 2015-04-28 05:29:00    37
#> 10 2015-04-28 09:14:00    58

df %>%
  mutate(date_col = date(Datetime)) %>%
  group_by(date_col) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   date_col   value
#>   <date>     <int>
#> 1 2015-04-27   252
#> 2 2015-04-28   161
```

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

using data.table

```
Test$Datetime <- as.Date(Test$Datetime)
DT<- data.table(Test )
DT[,sum(value),by = Datetime]

     Datetime   V1
1: 2015-04-27 46.1
2: 2015-04-28  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right path - try : 
    `summarise(newVal = sum(energy$value) )`
for your summarise call.
`df<- energy %>% group_by(datetime) %>% summarise(sum =sum(value)) )`

Comment: When i run: df %>% group_by(energy$datetime) %>% summarize(newval =sum(energy$value))

I get an Error: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: You have copied the code incorrectly. See my comment to your question. `df` here stands for dataframe. Is your dataframe called `df`? That is, is your data stored in an object called `df`? It looks like your data is stored in an object called `energy`, so use `energy` instead of `df`.

Comment: Hi - group_by() from the dplyr lib works like this:  `group_by(data, var,...)`. If you use the `%>%` command you put your data out front like this - `data %>% group_by(variableInData)`.  Assign this to another variable:  `dfGroup <- energy %>% group_by(datetime) %>% summarise(value)`  You do have to fix the datetime first as you did in your previous code.  Cheers!   Notice the `<-` Operator