# Convert column of ints to year

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so please no hate. I want to convert the below column of ints to a column of years

Convert this:
`Date: int 189507 189508 189509 ...`

To this:
`Year: int 1895 1895 1895`

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read_csv("noaa-central-park.csv")
year <- df$Date 
df <- transform(df, year = as.Date(as.character(year), "%Y"))
tempByYears <- group_by(df, year)
```

**Question:** I still get a year-month-day format as shown below. How to fix?

[image]

Sources: [Stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575785/r-group-by-date-and-summarize-the-values), [group_by() video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iE1iQgoi5Q)

Comment: A `Date` in R is a year-month-day. If you only specify a year, you get today's date in that year - note 03-25 in every row. Could you just sub-string - `substr(df$Date,1,4)` ?

Comment: There's a `yearmon` class defined in pkg:zoo. I'm guessing knowledge of the other features offered by this highly valuable package might be useful in research about long time series.

Comment: `transform(df,year=year(as.Date(as.character(year),"%Y")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the value in `Date` is Year + Month, in the format `%Y%m`. In that case, it would be better not to read it into R as in integer. You could specify that `Date` be a character, for example.

I'm using `df1` for the data frame variable name because `df` may cause confusion with the function of the same name.

```
df1 <- read_csv("noaa-central-park.csv", 
    col_types = cols(Date = col_character()))
```

Now assuming that every `Date` starts with a 4-digit year, the simplest way to get `year` is to extract the first 4 characters and convert to numeric:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(substring(Date, 1, 4))
```